# How to Pagination Without Page Reload Using Ajax In WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

With the help of stackoverflow users I made an ajax navigation with the WP_Query. The posts (which in my case are user orders) are loaded correctly. However, at the end of the work I realized that the result I was looking for was different.

#### What I want to do

What I was trying to achieve was a page navigation as it happens in the gif below. I achieved this with a plugin, but as I am trying to learn I would like to rely on custom code and not on plugins.[image]

#### What I did

The code I wrote does not navigate between pages but adds more posts to existing ones, so what it does is load more posts until you get too long a list of orders.

**My question**
can I modify the code I have to get ajax navigation between pages rather than load other posts? If it can be done, what is the right way to do this?  I am hoping for some possible changes otherwise I would have to start over.

**Template.php**

```
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/custom.js?<?php $FourDigitRandomNumber = mt_rand(00000,99999); echo $FourDigitRandomNumber; ?>" defer=""></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/custom.css?<?php $FourDigitRandomNumber = mt_rand(00000,99999); echo $FourDigitRandomNumber; ?>" />

<h3>Custom Endpoint</h3>

<?php
global $wp_query;

//Variable For Args Query
$paged = max( 1, (int) filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'pagina' ) );
$order_statuses = array('wc-completed');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_status'    => $order_statuses,
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
// Loop Content
if( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();

  //Here content
  // The order ID
  $order_id = $loop->post->ID;
   
  // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
  $order = wc_get_order($loop->post->ID);
  $items = $order->get_items();

  $orders_id = $order->get_id();
  $status =  wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );
  $date_created = $order->get_date_created()->date('d/m/Y');
  $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method_title();
  $order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();

  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item->get_name();
    $view_order = $order->get_view_order_url();

    // Get product image - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/
    $product = $item->get_product();
      if( $product instanceof WC_Product ){
       $order_img = $product->get_image();
      }

    //Get product download button 
    $downloads = $order->get_downloadable_items();
      if(is_array($downloads)) {
          foreach($downloads as $product){
           $download_button = '<a href="'. $product['download_url'] .'" target="_blank">Download</a>';
          } 
      } 

      echo '
      <table class="table_orders">
      <tr class="table_row_items">
      <td class="product_number">
           <span class="mobile title">Ordine</span>
           <span>#'. esc_attr($orders_id) .'</span>
          </td>

          <td class="product_name">
           <span class="mobile title">Prodotto</span>
           <a href="'. wp_kses_post($view_order) .'">'. wp_kses_post($product_name) .'</a>
          </td>

          <td class="product_data">
           <span class="mobile title">Data</span>
           <span>'. wp_kses_post($date_created) .'</span>
          </td>

          <td class="product_price">
           <span class="mobile title">Prezzo</span>
           <span>'. wp_kses_post($order_total) .'</span>
          </td>

          <td class="product_status">
           <span class="mobile title">Stato</span>
           <span class="label ' . $order->get_status() . '">'. wp_kses_post($status) .'</span>
          </td>

          <td class="product_action">
           <span class="mobile title">File</span>
           <a target=”_blank” href="'. esc_url($view_order) .'">Visualizza<i class="fa-duotone fa-eye"></i></a>
          </td>
      </tr>    
      </table> 
 ';
  } 
}
    
    // Pagination
      ?><div id="pagination" class="container-pagination"><?php 
        $args = array(
      'base'          => esc_url( 'https://motustrength.it/account/custom/' ) . '%_%',
      'format'        => '?pagina=%#%',
      'total'         => $loop->max_num_pages,
      'current'       => $paged,
      'show_all'      => false,
      'end_size'      => 3,
      'mid_size'      => 3,
      'prev_next'     => true,
        'prev_text' => __('<i class="fa-regular fa-angle-left"></i><span>Indietro</span>'), 
      'next_text' => __('<span>Avanti</span><i class="fa-regular fa-angle-right"></i>'),
      'type'          => 'plain',
      'add_args'      => false,
      'add_fragment'  => ''
      ); 
      echo paginate_links($args); 
    
}  

else {
   ?><div class="no-downloads-msg">Nessun download disponibile, non hai ancora acquistato alcun prodotto.</div><?php
   } 
 ?></div><?php
```

**File.js**

```
(function( $ ) {
    
    $.fn.wpPagination = function( options ) {
        options = $.extend({
            links: "a",
            action: "pagination",
            ajaxURL: "https://" + location.host + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            next: ".next",
            previous: ".previous",
            disablePreviousNext: false
        }, options);
        
        function WPPagination( element ) {
            this.$el = $( element );
            this.init();
        }
        
        WPPagination.prototype = {
            init: function() {
                this.createLoader();
                this.handlePreviousNextLinks();
                this.handleLinks();
            },
            createLoader: function() {
                var self = this;
                self.$el.before( "<div id='pagination-loader'></div>" );
            },
            handlePreviousNextLinks: function() {
                var self = this;
                var $previous = $( options.previous, self.$el );
                var $next = $( options.next, self.$el );
                
                if( options.disablePreviousNext ) {
                    $previous.remove();
                    $next.remove();
                } else {
                    $previous.addClass( "clicked" );
                    $next.addClass( "clicked" );
                }
            },
            handleLinks: function() {
                var self = this,
                    $links = $( options.links, self.$el ),
                    $loader = $( "#pagination-loader" );
                    
                    $links.click(function( e ) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var $a = $( this ),
                            url = $a.attr( "href" ),
                            page = url.match( /\d+/ ), // Get the page number
                            pageNumber = page[0],
                            data = {
                                action: options.action, // Pass the AJAX action name along with the page number
                                page: pageNumber
                            };
                            
                          if( !$a.hasClass( "clicked" ) ) { // We don't want duplicated posts
                            
                            $loader.show(); // Show the loader
                            
                            $.get( options.ajaxURL, data, function( html ) {
                                $loader.hide(); // Hide the loader
                                $loader.before( html ); // Insert posts
                                $a.addClass( "clicked" ); // Flag the current link as clicked
                            });
                            
                           }
                    });
            }
        };
        
        return this.each(function() {
            var element = this;
            var pagination = new WPPagination( element );
        });
    };
    
})( jQuery );

(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
        if( $( "#pagination" ).length ) {
            $( "#pagination" ).wpPagination();
        }
    });
    
})( jQuery );
```

**functions.php**

```
// Ajax Pagination
function my_get_posts_for_pagination() {
    $paged = $_GET['page']; // Page number
    $html = '';
    $pag = 0;

    if( filter_var( intval( $paged ), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) ) {
        
        $order_statuses = array('wc-completed');
        $pag = $paged;
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'shop_order',
            'paged'          => $pag, // Uses the page number passed via AJAX
            'posts_per_page' => 4, // Change this as you wish
         'post_status'    => $order_statuses,
            'customer_id'    => get_current_user_id(),
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        
        // The Wordpress post loop
        if( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
             $loop->the_post();
                // Build the HTML string with your post's contents
            // The order ID
            $order_id = $loop->post->ID;
   
            // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
            $order = wc_get_order($loop->post->ID);
            $items = $order->get_items();

            $orders_id = $order->get_id();
            $status =  wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );
            $date_created = $order->get_date_created()->date('d/m/Y');
            $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method_title();
            $order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();

            foreach ( $items as $item ) {
               $product_name = $item->get_name();
               $view_order = $order->get_view_order_url();

               // Get product image - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/
               $product = $item->get_product();
               if( $product instanceof WC_Product ){
                  $order_img = $product->get_image();
               }

               //Get product download button 
               $downloads = $order->get_downloadable_items();
               if(is_array($downloads)) {
                  foreach($downloads as $product){
                     $download_button = '<a href="'. $product['download_url'] .'" target="_blank">Download</a>';
                  } 
               }
               
                    //What you want to show
               echo '
                  <table class="table_orders">
                  <tr class="table_row_items">
                     <td class="product_number">
                      <span class="mobile title">Ordine</span>
                      <span>#'. esc_attr($orders_id) .'</span>
                     </td>

                     <td class="product_name">
                      <span class="mobile title">Prodotto</span>
                      <a href="'. wp_kses_post($view_order) .'">'. wp_kses_post($product_name) .'</a>
                     </td>

                     <td class="product_data">
                      <span class="mobile title">Data</span>
                      <span>'. wp_kses_post($date_created) .'</span>
                     </td>

                     <td class="product_price">
                      <span class="mobile title">Prezzo</span>
                      <span>'. wp_kses_post($order_total) .'</span>
                     </td>

                     <td class="product_status">
                      <span class="mobile title">Stato</span>
                      <span class="label ' . $order->get_status() . '">'. wp_kses_post($status) .'</span>
                     </td>

                     <td class="product_action">
                      <span class="mobile title">File</span>
                      <a target=”_blank” href="'. esc_url($view_order) .'">Visualizza<i class="fa-duotone fa-eye"></i></a>
                     </td>
                  </tr>    
                  </table> 
               ';
               }
               wp_reset_query();
           }
       }
    }   
    echo $html;
    exit();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_pagination', 'my_get_posts_for_pagination' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pagination', 'my_get_posts_for_pagination' );
```

Comment: `What I was trying to achieve was a page navigation as it happens in the gif below. I achieved this with a plugin, but as I am trying to learn I would like to rely on custom code and not on plugins.` Sometimes we have to decide if it's worth our time to re-invent the wheel that's already been invented. If there's a well written lightweight plugin to do the task, then use it.

Comment: The point is this. The plugin in question does not work with woocommerce endpoints. So I have to create each shop / account page outside the endpoint. So it's not convenient from this point of view.